# Counting non stop words in an NLTK corpus

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, stop-words

In python using NLTK how would I find a count of the number of non stop words in a document filtered by category?

I can figure out how to get the words in a corpus filtered by a category e.g. all the words in the brown corpus for category ‘news’ is:

```
text = nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories=category)
```

And separately I can figure out how to get all the words for a particular document e.g. all the words in the document ‘cj47’ in the brown corpus is:

```
text = nltk.corpus.brown.words(fileids='cj47')
```

And then I can loop through the results and count up the words that are not stopwords e.g.

```
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
for w in text:    
    if w.lower() not in stopwords:
#found a non stop words
```

But how do I put it together so that I am filtering by category for a particular document? If I try to specify a category  and a filter at the same time e.g.

```
 text = nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories=category, fields=’cj47’)
```

I get an error saying:

```
 ValueError: Specify fields or categories, not both
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get fileids for a category:

   `fileids = nltk.corpus.brown.fileids(categories=category)`
2. For each file, count the non-stopwords:

   `for f in fileids:
       words = nltk.corpus.brown.words(fileids=f)
       sum = sum([1 for w in words if w.lower() not in stopwords])
       print "Document %s: %d non-stopwords." % (f, sum)`